# A book or a PDF with ALL the conversions between units. Does it exist?

Tags: resource-recommendations, dimensional-analysis, unit-conversion

I was wondering if there is a book (or a pdf) with all the conversion factors, equations etc., and also between different systems like all the conversions between the SI and cgs and so on.

It's so frustrating to forget some conversion factor and spend hours to find the right answer.

Comment: Why are you spending hours? You should be converting all quantities into one consistent set of units at the beginning of the calculation, carrying the units throughout the calculation, and checking at the end to make sure that your result has the expected units.

Comment: it is a long process. sometimes, when you work and you have to plot a graph, you just need a conversion factor.

Comment: Many people today look up conversion factors on the internet.

Comment: Why don't you make a chart for yourself? Do it with LaTeX and learn that also. Use the package "siunitx" for formatting your number and "booktabs" for the tables. That would be some hours well-spent.

Answer (score 2):

whenever I need a conversion factor, I search on-line. Typing CONVERSION FACTOR brings up a long list of useful sites, and each offers a long list of easy-to-use conversion tables.